# Pinterest pin widget not working on Blogger

Tags: javascript, widget, blogger, pinterest

I am trying to use the profile widget from Pinterest found [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/widget-builder/#do_embed_user).

The generated code added to my blog page is the following:

```
<a data-pin-do="embedPin" data-pin-terse="true" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/340795896779022349/"></a>
```

I've modified and included the pinit.js above the `</body>` tag in the HTML template of the blog with the following code:

```
<script data-pin-hover='true' src='//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

The result is the pin being embedded in my page, but when the mouse hover over the pin, the pin button does not appear.

Comment: Can you share the blog on which this happens?

Comment: I have a test page at: http://athensfever.blogspot.gr/2012/05/athens-traffic.html. Currently, the pinit.js script is the follwing: <script async='' defer='' src='//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js'/>.